# How to calculate and show a percentage with crossfilter and dc.numbedisplay?

Tags: javascript, reduce, crossfilter

I'm trying to use dc.numberDisplay on the following array to display a percentage of the total number of Trues over the Total.

```
var data = [
  {Bool: "True", val: 20},
  {Bool: "True", val: 20},
  {Bool: "True", val: 20},
  {Bool: "False", val: 20},
  {Bool: "False", val: 20}
];
```

The result I'm going for is 60%, since the total of the True's is 60 and the Total of all the data is 100.

Currently, I can get the aggregate of the values using the following:

HTML:

```
<h1 id = "numberDisplay">here</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
dc.numberDisplay('#numberDisplay')
        .valueAccessor(function(d){return d})
        .group(ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d){return d["val"];}))
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"));
dc.redrawAll();
```

I can also get the sum of the the values with True with this

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

ndxFilter = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Bool; });
ndxFilter.filter('True');


dc.numberDisplay('#numberDisplay')
        .valueAccessor(function(d){return d})
        .group(ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d){return d["val"];}))
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"));
dc.redrawAll();
```

I'm having difficulty putting these together to get a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

With native javascript I would do something like this:

```
var len = data.length,
    trues = data.filter(function(d){return d.Bool === "True"}).length,
    percentage = trues / len * 100;

document.getElementById('numberDisplay').value = percentage+"%";
```